# How to create a C# cmdlet that supports dot notation

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a cmdlet in C# that would provide properties that could be used in the PowerShell environment.  I'm currently using PowerShell 3.0.

In PowerShell I'm looking for this kind of usage:

cmdlet.Property.WrappedObject.ItsProperties

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger I know how to write a cmdlet, thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, a cmdlet is of the form Verb-Noun . It does not have a dot notation. However, a cmdlet can return any .NET object as a result. So you can have a C# class such as:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string ObjectName { get; set; }
   public int ObjectValue { get; set; }
}
```

You can then have a PowerShell cmdlet, Get-MyObject, that returns that .NET object, such as:

```
$obj = Get-MyObject
```

And you can then use dot notation to get to the properties within the return object:

```
Write-Host $obj.ObjectName
Write-Host $obj.ObjectValue
```